# Gradle Errors while updating

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am working on a very old project[image]

Its gradle version and plugin was very outdated

When I am trying to update both to the latest version, its giving me lot of errors.
Errors:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_calorie_counter-master'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_calorie_counter-master'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
...
```

I am not even able to use constraint layout and other new stuffs.

My gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vladnamik.developer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1+'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Gradel properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Gradel wrapper:

```
#Sat Mar 04 19:19:57 IST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Also my project is giving me AppCompatActivity errors(cannot resolve AppCompatActivity) but the app is working fine
[image]

Please can someone help me out I am very newbie in android development

Comment: update the Gradel wrapper file and try again with the below-snipped code                       
   #Sat Mar 04 19:19:57 IST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE IN THE WRAPPER GRADLE FILE WITH THE BELOW CONTENT

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

//CHANGE THIS LINE OF CODE.
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```